# How to disable auto updates in the Brave browser

Tags: chromium, brave, auto-updates

How to ***disable*** auto update in the brave browser?

I use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) to install software on my system. When I checked the version of my brave browser it was the latest version. I don't want this auto update since I have installed brave browser using chocolatey I would like to use choco to update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple places where you can disable the updater executable.

1. Prevent it from getting launched at startup with e.g. [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns):

- download and open it
- find `BraveSoftware Update` entry
- delete it

---

2. Stop automatic task runs in Task Scheduler:

- open `taskschd.msc`
- find `BraveSoftwareUpdateTaskUser[SID]` tasks, where `SID` is a long ID string
- <kbd>Right mouse button</kbd> them and click `Disable`

---

3. Disable some services:

- open `services.msc`
- find `Brave Update Service (brave)` and `Brave Update Service (bravem)`
- go to their `Properties` and set their `Startup type` to `Manual`

---

**Note 1**: any of this may get overwritten by next choco installs, depending on what the installer does.

**Note 2: I don't** recommend doing this. Browsers get important security updates and are one of the most vulnerable parts of the system. I don't see a reason to disable them, unless you're e.g. a web dev who needs to test with specific versions, but then other solutions exist for that.